# Google authentication in Desktop application

Tags: c#, winforms, google-oauth

I have a Web application that uses Google authentication using clientID, secret key and redirectUrl. Now I have another application that is a Windows Form app and want Google authentication using the same clientid as the one used in the Web application. How can I do authentication in the Windows app?

Answer (score 1):

There are several types of clients that you can create for accessing Google's authentication server.

1. web browser applications
2. native (other) applications
3. service accounts
4. mobile

Each type of client uses a different set of credentials and in some cases a different grant type.  For security reasons they are designed for use with the type of client that will be used to access it.

A web browser client is requires a redirect uri so that the authorization server knows were to return the credentials to.   A native installed application does not require a redirect uri because the authorization server knows to return the authorization to the same place that the call came from.

**Answer**: You can't use a web browser client in an installed application. You will need to [create a native (other) type of client](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp#creatingcred) in your project and use that.